# Firefox Or JavaScript, count the DOM

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom, bookmarklet, userscripts

I'm sure this is simple but I have no idea how to do it.
How do i count the amount of DOM elements in my HTML page? I wanted to do this in a userscript or bookmarklet but i have no idea how to start!

Comment: Do you want to know about the DOM nodes or DOM nodes that are HTML elements? The DOM includes things like text, comments, and attributes as nodes.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Use this for `Element` nodes:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("*").length
```

For any node, you can extend `Node` like this:

```
Node.prototype.countChildNodes = function() {
  return this.hasChildNodes()
    ? Array.prototype.slice.apply(this.childNodes).map(function(el) {
        return 1 + el.countChildNodes();
      }).reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue, index, array){
        return previousValue + currentValue;
      })
    : 0;
};
```

Then all you need to do is to call `document.countChildNodes`.

Comment: is there any way to add the number of elements inside iframes?

Comment: @corretge That would be possible if you have access to the `contentDocument`. Just iterate the elements you get with `document.getElementsByTagName("*")` and count them as 1 and for each `iframe` element node (`tagName==='IFRAME'`) add the number of elements in its `contentDocument` instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have another 'little' problem: Domains, protocols and ports must match. Normal :)

Comment: @corretge That’s due to [security reasons](http://www.w3.org/Security/wiki/Same_Origin_Policy).

Comment: This is not an actual count of all the dom nodes. It is a count of all of the elements within the document. Not including attributes, AJAX'ed XML and so on. So this is very inaccurate

Comment: @Blowsie The question was: “How do i count the amount of DOM elements in my HTML page?“ So why should I count all nodes?

Comment: So what is the best way to count *all* nodes including ajax'd xml, etc.?

Comment: To address the comments by @Blowsie and @JDSmith: The first and second solutions in this answer do two different things. The first method only counts Element nodes, it doesn't count other DOM nodes like text nodes. The second method (`document.countChildNodes();`) counts all descendant nodes. So, for example, I just ran both methods on a random HTML page, the first returned a count of 202, the  second a count of 454.

Answer (score 3):

// You could use the same method to get the count of each tag, if it matters

```
  function tagcensus(pa){
    pa= pa || document;
    var O= {},
    A= [], tag, D= pa.getElementsByTagName('*');
    D= A.slice.apply(D, [0, D.length]);
    while(D.length){
        tag= D.shift().tagName.toLowerCase();
        if(!O[tag]) O[tag]= 0;
        O[tag]+= 1;
    }
    for(var p in O){
        A[A.length]= p+': '+O[p];
    }
    A.sort(function(a, b){
        a= a.split(':')[1]*1;
        b= b.split(':')[1]*1;
        return b-a;
    });
    return A.join(', ');
}
```

**alert(tagcensus())**

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript you can do

```
document.getElementsByTagName("*").length
```

In jQuery you can do

```
jQuery('*').length
```